# IE gridview with flash content loading slowly

Tags: .net, flash, internet-explorer, optimization, gridview

In part of our application we have the ability to search for music.  The search results are loaded into a gridview which lists the song name, the artist, the royalty required for use, and a small flash object which plays a preview when clicked (wimpy button from [this site](http://www.wimpyplayer.com/))

When the users search returns a large number of results, it takes a surprisingly long time for the gridview to load.  I've narrowed it down to the flash object: IE seems to wait to display the gridview until the flash object has loaded for each row.  Firefox instead renders the gridview and then loads the swf.

Is there a way to force IE to render the gridview at once, and load the swf after (like Firefox)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery and react to the finished renedering by adding flash content dynamicaly.

Comment: I'd hoped for something that was a little more robust (i.e.: not javascript-based) but if this is the way it has to be, it's the way it has to be.